# JOptionPane Custom JButtons are not closing after selecting

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a financial program in which after selecting the stock and selecting the price and quantity, we have two options on a joptionpane panel "buy" and "cancel".  For the life of my I can not get this to work.  Any help would be appreciated greatly. Thank you. I have the int buyNow as a field in the constructor.

```
final JButton buy = new JButton("Buy");
    buy.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
        {
            buyStock();
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
            double doubleBal = sql.getBalance().doubleValue();
            String bal = nf.format(doubleBal);
            jLabel_DisplayBalance.setText(bal);
            double doubleCash = sql.getCash().doubleValue();
            String cash = nf.format(doubleCash);
            jLabel_DisplayCash.setText(cash);
            double doubleStock = sql.getStock().doubleValue();
            String stock = nf.format(doubleStock);
            jLabel_DisplayStock.setText(stock);
            System.out.println(buyNow);
        }
    });
    final JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
        {
            System.out.println(buyNow);
        }
    });
    JButton[] buttons = {buy, cancel};
    buyNow = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(rootPane, getBuyOrSellPanel      ("Buy"), title, 
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, buttons, cancel);
```

I was testing with the system.out.println to see if it was getting the proper int value for the selected button but it only displays 0 for both buttons.  I have no clue why.

Comment: oops, answer corrected. The dialog returns an int to the array, not the selected item in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass in an array of JButtons but rather an array of String. And note that your cancel and buy ActionListeners won't work either and aren't necessary. Instead test the int array index returned to the buyNow variable. Inside an if block (tested using the equals method), act accordingly.

```
int buyNow = -1;
String[] options = {"Buy", "Cancel"};
buyNow = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(rootPane, getBuyOrSellPanel      ("Buy"), title, 
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, cancel);

if ("Buy".equals(options[buyNow])) {
    // code for "Buy" option
} else if ("Cancel".equals(options[buyNow])) {
    // code for "cancel" option
}
```

Comment: Thank you! A step in the right direction.  Now when I click on the x in the top right corner it gives me this java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: @user3003122: so now you know based on this error to test for this before using the index. You can figure out the fix, I'm confident.